# Soft keyboard over view in dialog ( jetpack compose view)

Tags: android-studio, android-compose-textfield

I have a dialog view like

```
Dialog(
    onDismissRequest = { openDialogCustom.value = false },
    properties = DialogProperties(
        dismissOnBackPress = true,
        dismissOnClickOutside = false
    )
) {
Column(Modifier.height(600.dp)) {
        Column(
            Modifier
                .background(Color.White)
                .padding(16.dp)
                .weight(1f,false)
                .verticalScroll(
                    rememberScrollState()
                )
        ) {

   // list of textField views
//Button view
        }
    }
```

when I select textfield, the soft keyboard appear and over the button and I cannot scroll too see the bottom button. I need some helps to scroll view to see the bottom button in dialog.
Image for dialog[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use adjust pan|resize option in the manifest file for the activity.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: You may misunderstand my problem.
I have still added adjust size in manifest, it just work with traditional view, not compose view and I want my bottom buttons  can see when keyboard appear